# How to disable Accessibility "TalkBack" in your application?

Tags: android, accessibility, text-to-speech

My application uses **TTS (text-to-speech) Engine**, and the conflict I am running into is that Accessibility **Talkback** settings override anything TTS tries to say. I would like to disable the phone's talkback option if using my application.

Is there some sort of permission to handle this? I have not been able to find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not allowed unless the phone is rooted. The accessibility functions on the phone are not to be changed by a developer, as a blind person may need them to use the phone.

Comment: O, wow! That is a bummer. Just a side, but that seems like a blunder move. My app is actually for the Blind, and it would be nice to be able to use my own TTS and Voice Recognition in my app without accessibility disabling, and preventing actions. Anyway, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Yeah, Android doesn't really want people to mess with the Accessibility settings. You could try to mute the Accessibility app, but that would probably be unwise.

Comment: Is there a way to mute it inside my app? Because I wonder if TTS Engine would work if it were muted.

Comment: The ability might exist with a rooted phone, but it would take a lot of work, and would take lots of permission, I'll see if I can find an answer.

Comment: It would be great if we raised an enhancement request for this. Applications can handle certain circumstances better than TalkBack, but probably not all of them. Allowing the user to override which actions can be handled by an an external application would benefit everyone.

Comment: Yeah, though if one dev screws up, the disabled may not be able to use their phone.

Comment: Wow, it's unbelievable that apps are not allowed to override the system's own accessibility features. That means Google assumes they've come up with the best possible accessibility features and no application developer may be able to design anything better. Which is a wrong assumption.

Comment: Is there at least a way to block the injected scripts within web content in a WebView?

Comment: Still not allowed to activating talkback programmatically ? I cannot find enough information about that.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's late, but I had the same problem few days ago.
If you want to "ovverride" the TalkBack with your own TTS engine you can simply add:

```
android:importantForAccessibility = "no"
```

to each view inside your Layout.
Now you can call your `TtsSpeak()` method inside your Activity.

IMPORTANT: This does not turn off the TalkBack App, but it will allow you to have a little bit more control over your App.

Comment: as of Android 19 you can also set it to `noHideDescendants` for the parent view to disable it completely

Answer (score -2):

Lg P875: having tried out Accessibility mode, the phone locked me out from scrolling - thus unable access Availability facility to reverse process.  Nothing in User manual.
By accident I found selecting Settings icon, tap twice followed by long push on same icon. The screen released and I was able to terminate Talkback key.  All back to normal, no thanks to LG user manual

Comment: When TalkBack is enabled, sliding a single finger over the screen tells the device to read the `contentDescription` associated with each element, without activating any buttons. This takes priority over scrolling. In order to scroll in this mode, you can use two fingers.